# Read rdtsc in Python

Tags: python, rdtsc

Is there any way to read out the timestamp-counter on x86 CPUs in Python?

I know that using `rdtscp` is bad and using `rdtsc` is even worse. But trust me I really need that value, or at least some approximation of that value.

Any ideas?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need it?

Comment: I was doing work for my M.Sc. thesis back then. The thesis is about redundant execution of applications. Deterministic execution is a key issue there, so I wanted to get the system's TSC to hand it down to the two, three or more replicas of the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With normal python, time.clock() is the most accurate thing you will get.

```
time.clock()
```

> On Unix, return the current processor time as a floating point number
>   expressed in seconds. The precision, and in fact the very definition
>   of the meaning of “processor time”, depends on that of the C function
>   of the same name, but in any case, this is the function to use for
>   benchmarking Python or timing algorithms.
>
> On Windows, this function returns wall-clock seconds elapsed since the
>   first call to this function, as a floating point number, based on the
>   Win32 function QueryPerformanceCounter(). The resolution is typically
>   better than one microsecond.

If you really want to have processor ticks, just remember the time which is needed to execute this python call - so Python is not the right language to do microsecond time measurement.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58569361/attributeerror-module-time-has-no-attribute-clock-in-python-3-8 https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter_ns https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.process_time_ns (First `import time`, then...) Use `time.perf_counter()` or `time.process_time_ns()` instead now. In this and the general case, you probably want `time.perf_counter_ns()`, e.g. to subtract `end - start` for benchmarking or something.