# AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock' in Python 3.8

Tags: python, attributeerror, pycrypto, python-3.8

I have written code to generate public and private keys. It works great at Python 3.7 but it fails in Python 3.8. I don't know how it fails in the latest version. Help me with some solutions.

Here's the Code:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA


def generate_keys():
    modulus_length = 1024
    key = RSA.generate(modulus_length)
    pub_key = key.publickey()
    private_key = key.exportKey()
    public_key = pub_key.exportKey()
    return private_key, public_key


a = generate_keys()
print(a)
```

Error in Python 3.8 version:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 18, in <module>
    a = generate_keys()
  File "temp.py", line 8, in generate_keys
    key = RSA.generate(modulus_length)
  File "/home/paulsteven/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py", line 508, in generate
    obj = _RSA.generate_py(bits, rf, progress_func, e)    # TODO: Don't use legacy _RSA module
  File "/home/paulsteven/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Crypto/PublicKey/_RSA.py", line 50, in generate_py
    p = pubkey.getStrongPrime(bits>>1, obj.e, 1e-12, randfunc)
  File "/home/paulsteven/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Crypto/Util/number.py", line 282, in getStrongPrime
    X = getRandomRange (lower_bound, upper_bound, randfunc)
  File "/home/paulsteven/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Crypto/Util/number.py", line 123, in getRandomRange
    value = getRandomInteger(bits, randfunc)
  File "/home/paulsteven/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Crypto/Util/number.py", line 104, in getRandomInteger
    S = randfunc(N>>3)
  File "/home/paulsteven/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Crypto/Random/_UserFriendlyRNG.py", line 202, in read
    return self._singleton.read(bytes)
  File "/home/paulsteven/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Crypto/Random/_UserFriendlyRNG.py", line 178, in read
    return _UserFriendlyRNG.read(self, bytes)
  File "/home/paulsteven/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Crypto/Random/_UserFriendlyRNG.py", line 129, in read
    self._ec.collect()
  File "/home/paulsteven/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Crypto/Random/_UserFriendlyRNG.py", line 77, in collect
    t = time.clock()
AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'
```

Comment: referenced here in the Crytpo lib : https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/issues/283 But the ticket seems not to be closed since quite a year.

Comment: The error is in line 18 of a 12 line program. Show us the code that produced the error.

Answer (score 124):

From the [Python 3.8 doc](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html):

> The function `time.clock()` has been removed, after having been deprecated since Python 3.3: use `time.perf_counter()` or `time.process_time()` instead, depending on your requirements, to have well-defined behavior. (Contributed by Matthias Bussonnier in [bpo-36895](https://bugs.python.org/issue36895).)

Answer (score 108):

Check if you are using PyCrypto, if yes, uninstall it and install [PyCryptodome](https://pypi.org/project/pycryptodome/) which is a fork of PyCrypto

PyCrypto is dead as mentioned on [project issue page](https://github.com/pycrypto/pycrypto/issues/173)

Since both these libraries can coexist, it could be an issue too

```
pip3 uninstall PyCrypto
pip3 install -U PyCryptodome
```

Comment: use --user instead of -U if you get a permission error

Comment: This is also the solution if you have this error when running gsutil rsync. See [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/1127)

Answer (score 78):

`time.clock()` was *removed in 3.8* because it had [platform-dependent behavior](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/time.html?highlight=time%20clock#time.clock):

- On **Unix**, this returns the current **processor time** (in seconds)
- On **Windows**, this returns **wall-clock time** (in seconds)

  ```
  # I ran this test on my dual-boot system as demonstration:
  print(time.clock()); time.sleep(10); print(time.clock())
  # Linux:    0.0382 --------------------------->  0.0384
  # Windows: 26.1224 ---------------------------> 36.1566
  ```

So  which function to pick instead?

- **Processor Time**: This is how long this specific process spends actively being executed on the CPU. Sleep, waiting for a web request, or time when only other processes are executed will not contribute to this.

  - Use `time.process_time()`
- **Wall-Clock Time**: This refers to how much time has passed "on a clock hanging on the wall", i.e. outside real time.

  - Use `time.perf_counter()`

    - `time.time()` also measures wall-clock time but can be reset, so you could go back in time
    - `time.monotonic()` cannot be reset (monotonic = only goes  forward) but has lower precision than `time.perf_counter()`

Comment: Thank you for the information. I have installed `chatterbot` and obtained the error message. I will try to downgrade to Python 3.7.

Answer (score 21):

Necroposting this ugly monkey patch:

```
import time
time.clock = time.time
```

Works as a last resort, but not recommended.

Comment: Works well for AWS Lambda. Thanks!

Comment: Wow. Good to know that it is useful. Thanks for letting us know!

Comment: Much better approach than editing the cpython source code, which will fail again when you redeploy/reinstall

Comment: Best , on-go fix

Comment: What about `time.clock = time.process_time` works also, right?

Comment: As of Python 3.3 `time.clock = time.perf_counter` has a better precision.

Comment: @daparic `perf_counter`/`time` measures wall-clock time, whereas `process_time` measures processor time. Refer to my answer for what the difference is.

Answer (score 19):

**Reason:** `time.clock` is deprecated

**Solution:**

**Step 1**

- Just go to your ***C folder*** and search ***site-packages*** in the search bar. You will see the result like this:

[image: site-packages]

- ***Right click*** on this result marked as Red, and ***open file location***.
- Then look for *sqlalchemy/util/compat.py* file and open it. And search ***time.clock*** using ctrl+f and replace it with ***time.time***

**Step 2**

- Go to your error ***last line*** and go to that directory and open that particular file.
- search ***time.clock*** using ctrl+f and replace it with ***time.time***

Comment: step 2 smoothly worked, easy and fast , thank you :)

Comment: The easiest soln.

Answer (score 5):

Go to the the code C:\Users\Mr\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject2\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util and select compat.py and search for `time.clock` in code.

Then replace `time.clock` with `time.time` and save it.

Comment: Does this apply to OP's situation? Is modifying the code of a library like this really a good idea?

Comment: although it may not the right and appropriate answer but that answer worked for me since I had a little experience with python

Answer (score 4):

```
AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'
```

It is deprecated as said which means just use the latest versions of libraries that have that module. For example, depending on the dependency you have, Remove and Install

> Crypto==1.4.1, or Mako==1.1.2 or SQLAlchemy==1.3.6     //etc

The idea is you don't have to downgrade your python version as this will catch up with you later. Just update the packages to more late ones which are compatible with Python 3.8

Answer (score 3):

The module you use to generate key call a method that have been depreciated since python 3.3 [time.clock()](https://bugs.python.org/issue36895).

You could downgrade to python 3.7 or change the source code to replace it. You should open an issue for that as well.

Answer (score 3):

`time.clock` is used in many old libraries.
Now that `time.clock` is removed, one must click on the path given in the error.
This will navigate you to the line where `time.clock` is written, and just change it to `time.time`.

Answer (score 2):

Open the file and go to the line as pointed in the error message, change the `time.clock()` line to `time.perf_counter()`, if it still doesn't work modify it to `time.time`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue for encrypting a string using AES in my project neehack.com and I fixed it by updating `venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Crypto/Random/_UserFriendlyRNG.py` line 77 to `t = time.time()` and it is now fixed.

Comment: `time.time()` and `time.clock()` are not compatible. You should replace it with `time.perf_counter()` instead which behaves in a more similar way

Answer (score 1):

In my case I replace **time.clock()** with **time.time()**

Answer (score 0):

If you have database involved, upgrade it.

```
pip install --upgrade flask_sqlalchemy
```

Answer (score 0):

Just open File "/home/paulsteven/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Crypto/Random/_UserFriendlyRNG.py", line 77

and change from

```
 t = time.clock()
```

to

```
 t = time.time
```

Answer (score 0):

Open file that debug error line.
And change t = time.clock()  to t = time.time

Answer (score 0):

testing on python3.6 env :

```
>>> print("%s %s" % (time.process_time(), time.clock()))
>>> 0.288050639 0.288056
```

that mean process_time is what the lib require.

Answer (score 0):

**time.clock() replacing with time.time() worked for me.**

time.process_time() didn't work for me and created other issues like float error etc.