# OpenAI "gym" Library throws a NoneType error on env.render()

Tags: python, machine-learning, openai-gym, q-learning

This is my first time working with machine learning libraries, I used to make it all myself, and when I did it worked, but I guess that when everyone tells you not to do the job yourself and let the libraries do it for you, you eventually try, and I tried "gym" of OpenAI on python, my code is very simple(I found it on a youtube video that explains how to use this library since I had no idea what I am getting into)

```
    import gym

env = gym.make("MountainCar-v0")
env.reset()

done = False

while not done:
    action = 2
    newState, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
    env.render()

env.close()
```

this code returns me this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\TestOnGymLibrary\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet__init__.py", line 378, in **getattr**
>       return getattr(self._module, name)
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_default'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/TestOnGymLibrary/me/RoeeHerzovich/TestOnGymLibrary
>
> /Core.py", line 11, in 
>       env.render()
>     File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\TestOnGymLibrary\venv\lib\site-packages\gym\core.py", line 235, in render
>       return self.env.render(mode, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\TestOnGymLibrary\venv\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\classic_control\mountain_car.py", line 78, in render
>       from gym.envs.classic_control import rendering
>     File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\TestOnGymLibrary\venv\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\classic_control\rendering.py", line 27, in 
>       from pyglet.gl import *
>     File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\TestOnGymLibrary\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\gl__init__.py", line 239, in 
>       import pyglet.window
>     File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\TestOnGymLibrary\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\window__init__.py", line 1896, in 
>       gl._create_shadow_window()
>     File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\TestOnGymLibrary\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\gl__init__.py", line 208, in _create_shadow_window
>       _shadow_window = Window(width=1, height=1, visible=False)
>     File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\TestOnGymLibrary\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\window\win32__init__.py", line 134, in **init**
>       super(Win32Window, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\TestOnGymLibrary\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\window__init__.py", line 501, in **init**
>       display = get_platform().get_default_display()
>     File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\TestOnGymLibrary\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\window__init__.py", line 1845, in get_default_display
>       return pyglet.canvas.get_display()
>     File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\TestOnGymLibrary\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\canvas__init__.py", line 77, in get_display
>       from pyglet.app import displays
>     File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\TestOnGymLibrary\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\app__init__.py", line 175, in 
>       event_loop = EventLoop()
>     File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\TestOnGymLibrary\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\app\base.py", line 119, in **init**
>       self.clock = clock.get_default()
>     File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\TestOnGymLibrary\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet__init__.py", line 384, in **getattr**
>       **import**(import_name)
>     File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\TestOnGymLibrary\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\clock.py", line 166, in 
>       _default_time_function = time.clock
>   AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'

I tried looking in places for this, but I haven't seen that...
I have gym, matplotlib and pyglet installed, I checked them and I even tried to --upgrade them and it said it is already upgraded, so I don't know what is going on. Can anyone please help me with it?

I appreciate all of your comments :)

Comment: i think you will have to find and check code for `"MountainCar-v0"` and see why `render()` expect some extra argument.

Comment: Oh damn, that means digging deep into openAI's gym library.... oof... this is why I hate being dependent on libraries and prefer doing things on my own... I'll look into it, or at least, I'll try, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The true error comes from the bottom of the trace you posted:

`_default_time_function = time.clock AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'`

This error has been addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58569361/attributeerror-module-time-has-no-attribute-clock-in-python-3-8).

Options:

Find where time.clock() is being called, and change it to time.perf_counter()

Downgrade to 3.7

Comment: I have changed time.clock to time.pref_counter() and it raised a different error:

>line 251, in __init__
    self.next_ts = self.time()
>TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

Except for the time.perf_counter() there was another thing that needed to be changed. I have written it all in here.
Thanks to everyone who helped me here

Answer:

Class: Clock.py
Row: 166
old: _default_time_function = time.clock
changed to: _default_time_function = time.perf_counter()

Class: Clock.py
Row: 251
old: self.next_ts = self.time()
changed to: self.next_ts = self.time

Answer (score 0):

This script should workm in google colab

```
!apt install xvfb -y
!pip install pyvirtualdisplay
!pip install piglet
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1400, 900))
display.start()
```