# Is this a bug on gensim hdp model for python 3.8?

Tags: python-3.x, time, gensim, python-3.8

I want to use the HDP model from `gensim` to get the number of topics for my corpus, I already used this corpus and dictionary to train a regular LDA model from `gensim` and it works fine. But now when I do

```
hdp = models.HdpModel(bow_corpus, dictionary)
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "models.py", line 185, in <module>
    hdp = models.HdpModel(bow_corpus, dictionary)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gensim/models/hdpmodel.py", line 391, in __init__
    self.update(corpus)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gensim/models/hdpmodel.py", line 467, in update
    start_time = time.clock()
AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'
```

Is this a bug?

```
$ python --version
Python 3.8.2 (default, Feb 26 2020, 22:21:03)
```

Edit to add more system information

```
>>> print(gensim.__version__)
3.8.1

uname -a
Linux ** 5.5.9-arch1-2 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu, 12 Mar 2020 23:01:33 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: It would help if you added the version of `gensim` you use and the OS platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are coming across an issue caused by [deprecation of `clock` function of `time` module](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/time.html#time.clock). It has been [deprecated since Python v. 3.3 and removed in v. 3.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58569361/attributeerror-module-time-has-no-attribute-clock-in-python-3-8).

To resolve it you have 2 options:

1. Try to upgrade `gensim` if you do not have the newest version.
2. Try to downgrade Python.