# Compile several PY files into EXE

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, exe, pyinstaller

I have several py files (PyQt5 small application with several windows) which I would like to compile into 1 exe file.
I tried to use pyinstaller with the following command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

but at some point I get this error message:

```
  File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 244, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 160, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 422, in assemble
    self.graph.process_post_graph_hooks()
  File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 311, in process_post_graph_hooks
    module_hook.post_graph()
  File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 417, in post_graph
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 383, in _load_hook_module
    self._hook_module = importlib_load_source(
  File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 797, in importlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 462, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 962, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 787, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 265, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 702, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-sqlalchemy.py", line 30, in <module>
    dialects = eval(dialects.strip())
  File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

unexpected EOF: usually means there is an open loop, or maybe a missing parenthesis somewhere.
But I tried to look for it everywhere and I didn't find it, also my code is running properly from PyCharm. 
So Im wondering if this error really exist, or just a bug when compiling many py files together from pyinstaller?
Any idea?
Thanks a lot for help!

After typing...

```
import sqlalchemy.dialects
print(sqlalchemy.dialects.__all__)
```

I get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PC/Desktop/mesprojets/nouvo/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    import sqlalchemy.dialects
  File "D:\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy.sql import (
  File "D:\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import (
  File "D:\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\expression.py", line 32, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy import util, exc
  File "D:\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .compat import callable, cmp, reduce, defaultdict, py25_dict, \
  File "D:\PYTHON\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 202, in <module>
    time_func = time.clock
AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: [This file](https://github.com/cleverplugs/pyinstaller/blob/master/PyInstaller/hooks/hook-sqlalchemy.py) looks to be suspect. What does `import sqlalchemy.dialects;print sqlalchemy.dialects.__all__` print when you run it?

Comment: I edited the post. Yes I get a big error message, it seems that you pushing me in the right direction!

Comment: I just ran , pip install sqlalchemy --upgrade , now it prints ('firebird', 'mssql', 'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite', 'sybase') . I ll try again to compile and see!

Comment: thanks! it looks like this is a python version issue. It was actually that exact code I pasted that was being run by the pyinstaller hook, which means it is meant for python 2.x, and based on the error message ([xreference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58569361/attributeerror-module-time-has-no-attribute-clock-in-python-3-8)), you're probably using python 3.8

Comment: oh okay, so yeah, upgrading packages may fix the issue too if the newer package is py3 compatible! And FWIW, that's the same output I got, so it sounds like you're close!

Comment: Yes! Im using Python 3.8 , Ok. so now, the file is compiled "successfully" in exe extension. this shows no errors anymore. Unfortunately, the exe file doesnt work. It's loading for few secs, then show a message error then closes instantly ( I had to record the screen to catch that message... too fast!)   https://imgur.com/a/9Km08zn

Comment: pip install pkg_resources
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pkg_resources (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pkg_resources

Comment: Oh cool, it's good that it's at least compiling. I think I have an idea for that error. Since this is a slightly different issue, could we move to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214374/discussion-between-christian-reall-fluharty-and-darkwarrior)?

Answer (score 2):

`pip install sqlalchemy --upgrade` This line worked for this issue

Comment: "pip install sqlalchemy --upgrade" didn't work... please help me

Answer (score 0):

pip install sqlalchemy --upgrade also resolved this error I was receiving while trying to create pyinstaller --onefiles for any script I was working on
"from compat import callable, cmp, reduce, defaultdict, py25_dict, \ ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'compat'". Incidentally, I also uninstalled Tensorflow as I was receiving a pip dependency resolver issue when initially running pip install sqlalchemy --upgrade