# Error when including 'channels' in installed_apps of Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-channels, channel

I am getting the following error when I add 'channels' in INSTALLED_APPS of Settings.py of Django.

```
AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock' for channels
```

Any idea why?

Comment: The clock function is depreciated in Python 3.8.You have to downgrade python version.You can have a look at it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58569361/attributeerror-module-time-has-no-attribute-clock-in-python-3-8

Comment: Is there anyway I can resolve this without downgrading python? @Ayush

Comment: Which version of channels module you have installed?

Comment: The latest version @Ayush