# Spyder doesn't launch

Tags: python, spyder

suddenly Spyder stop to launch with the following error. [image]

My OS is Windows

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock' in Python 3.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58569361/attributeerror-module-time-has-no-attribute-clock-in-python-3-8)

Comment: BTW we can still see your username...

Comment: BTW #2 "lunch" means eating something. What you mean is "launch".

Comment: install `resource` module using `pip install resource`, then try again

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the module `resource` in timing.py file, check it in your global python packages or in your workspace path,
and other reference problem, "clock attribute is not found in time package", for that, check documentation of your package or try to use the latest version of it.
.