# AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock' in MLFlow UI

Tags: python, python-datetime, python-dateutil, mlflow

I have successfully installed **MLFlow** using `pip install mlflow` but while running `mlflow ui` command in the console it gives the following **error**

```
    time_func = time.clock
AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'
```

I am aware of the fact that `time.clock` is deprecated for `Python v3.8` and above. How can I fix this, as I don't want to downgrade python version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock' in Python 3.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58569361/attributeerror-module-time-has-no-attribute-clock-in-python-3-8)

Comment: Open a [new issue on their repository's issue tracker](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues).

Comment: @Junkrat No, I did go through it It does not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using MLflow with Python 3.8.5, and it works just fine. I use Ubuntu 20.04, my MLflow version is 1.13.1, and my python was installed with miniconda.

As this is probably a version problem, you can try to install the same mlflow and python version that I am using. If it does not work, please share more information about your environment.

Answer (score 0):

#### Try updating your SQLAlchemy version

```
>>> pip install -U sqlalchemy
>>> mlflow ui
```

I jumped into a similar issue. Reference - [Github Issue](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/4030)