# Chatterbot installation working, but broken calls to variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, chatbot, chatterbot

I installed chatterbot in my terminal earlier today using virtual studio code's terminal. I saw that both chatterbot and chatterbot_corpus worked in installation. Then, I made the following python document:

EDIT: Turns out I should define a chatbot variable first.

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer

conversation = [
    "Hello",
    "Hi there!",
    "How are you doing?",
    "I'm doing great.",
    "That is good to hear",
    "Thank you.",
    "You're welcome."
]
bot = ChatBot('Maya')
trainer = ListTrainer(bot)

trainer.train(conversation)
```

This was my code

it says this however

```
bot = ChatBot('Maya')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Subha\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\chatterbot\chatterbot.py", line 34, in __init__
    self.storage = utils.initialize_class(storage_adapter, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Subha\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\chatterbot\utils.py", line 54, in initialize_class
    return Class(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Subha\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\chatterbot\storage\sql_storage.py", line 22, in __init__
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
  File "C:\Users\Subha\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import util as _util  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\Subha\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ._collections import coerce_generator_arg  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\Subha\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .compat import binary_types
  File "C:\Users\Subha\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 264, in <module>
    time_func = time.clock
AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this easily?

EDIT: I just updated python using pip install --upgrade ipython in terminal, but it didn't fix the issue

EDIT 2: Well now I tried updating a package using `pip install sqlalchemy --upgrade`

But now it gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Subha\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\chatterbot\chatterbot.py", line 34, in __init__
    self.storage = utils.initialize_class(storage_adapter, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Subha\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\chatterbot\utils.py", line 54, in initialize_class
    return Class(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Subha\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\chatterbot\storage\sql_storage.py", line 46, in __init__
    if not self.engine.dialect.has_table(self.engine, 'Statement'):
  File "C:\Users\Subha\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\sqlite\base.py", line 2009, in has_table
    self._ensure_has_table_connection(connection)
  File "C:\Users\Subha\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 341, in _ensure_has_table_connection
    raise exc.ArgumentError(
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: The argument passed to Dialect.has_table() should be a <class 'sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection'>, 
got <class 'sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine'>. Additionally, the Dialect.has_table() method is for internal dialect use only; please use ``inspect(some_engine).has_table(<tablename>>)`` for public API use.
```

I am in the latest version though

```
PS C:\Users\Subha> Python --version
Python 3.9.6
```

EDIT 3: Now it comes up with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Subha\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\chatterbot\chatterbot.py", line 34, in __init__
    self.storage = utils.initialize_class(storage_adapter, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Subha\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\chatterbot\utils.py", line 54, in initialize_class
    return Class(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Subha\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\chatterbot\storage\sql_storage.py", line 46, in __init__       
    # if not self.engine.dialect.has_table(self.engine, 'Statement'):
  File "C:\Users\Subha\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\sqlite\base.py", line 2009, in has_table
    self._ensure_has_table_connection(connection)
  File "C:\Users\Subha\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 341, in _ensure_has_table_connection
    raise exc.ArgumentError(
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: The argument passed to Dialect.has_table() should be a <class 'sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection'>, got <class 'sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine'>. Additionally, the Dialect.has_table() method is for internal dialect use only; please use ``inspect(some_engine).has_table(<tablename>>)`` for public API use.
```

Comment: the issue is solved here: https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/issues/1586

Comment: Sorry, I did check that out, but it doesn't solve my problem. I will edit my question

Comment: probably your Python version. how about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58569361/attributeerror-module-time-has-no-attribute-clock-in-python-3-8

Comment: Yeah, I just looked at that but I can't figure out how to get rid of time.clock like they suggested. I did update python, etc. though

Answer (score 0):

it seems the python upgrade worked with regard to the initial error on `time.clock`. This new error you are seeing is quite different to the previous one. In this case you need to go into `chatterbot/storage/sql_storage.py` and comment out `if not self.engine.dialect.has_table(self.engine, 'Statement'):` and leave only `self.create_database()`. This means that instead of checking whether a database table has been created which is triggering the error, it will just create the DB every time, which i expect to work fine.

```
# if not self.engine.dialect.has_table(self.engine, 'Statement'):
self.create_database()
```

Comment: Thank you! I did so. It still has a problem though , check edits

Answer (score 0):

1. Try getting the github files and put it into a folder of your choice. Make sure to run the setup.py
2. Make sure to have nltk installed
3. If you don't have chatterbot installed using the pip, then do it.

I did this and the error left. I'm also on Windows 11 and everything is updated.