# AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock' while running jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have anaconda3 installed and it has been working well until lately and I believe it happened after installing XGboost. While trying to start the notebooks I got an error on something to do with the version of tornado I uninstalled and then pip installed it. The error disappeared and now I am getting the following error while I run **jupyter notebook**:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\timing.py", line 27, in <module>
    import resource
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'resource'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 264, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 845, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 88, in inner
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 2151, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1759, in init_webapp
    self.web_app = NotebookWebApplication(
  File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 179, in __init__
    settings = self.init_settings(
  File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 302, in init_settings
    nbextensions_path=jupyter_app.nbextensions_path,
  File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1329, in nbextensions_path
    from IPython.paths import get_ipython_dir
  File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
  File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\embed.py", line 19, in <module>
    from IPython.terminal.ipapp import load_default_config
  File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 30, in <module>
    from IPython.core.magics import ScriptMagics
  File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .execution import ExecutionMagics
  File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\execution.py", line 46, in <module>
    from IPython.utils.timing import clock, clock2
  File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\timing.py", line 64, in <module>
    clocku = clocks = clock = time.clock
AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'
```

Comment: With your pip installation, did you switch to Python 3.8+? https://stackoverflow.com/a/58569410/1900384, run python with `--version` to check.

Comment: running Python 3.9.12

Comment: Then you have the answer to your question in the above-mentioned link. I consider your question a duplicate.

Comment: Tried to fix to no avail and ended up re-installing anaconda